# Running remote cqlsh to execute commands on Cassandra Cluster

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax, cqlsh, cassandra-cli

So I have a Cassandra cluster of 6 nodes on my Ubuntu machines, now I have got another machine running Windows Server 2008. I have installed DataStax Apache Cassandra on this new Windows machine, and I want to be able to run all the CQL commands from Windows machine onto Ubuntu machines.  So its like remote command execution.

I tried opening cqlsh in cmd using cqlsh with the IP of my one of the nodes and port like `cqlsh 192.168.4.7 9160`

But I can't seem to make it work.  Also I don't want to add the new machine to my existing cluster  Please suggest.

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using?

Comment: on nodes, its 1.2.9 and on windows its 2.0.12

Comment: Assuming that it isn't a network issue, it may be a mismatch between cqlsh versions.  What is the (exact) error that you are seeing?

Comment: yea u are right... i am getting this error.. Unsupported CQL version: Provided version 3.1.1 is not supported by this server (supported: 2.0.0, 3.0.5)

Comment: any workaround u could suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Provided version 3.1.1 is not supported by this server (supported: 2.0.0, 3.0.5)`
>
> any workaround u could suggest?

Basically, you have two options here.  The harder one would be to upgrade your cluster (the tough, long-term solution).  But there have been many [improvements](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1) since 1.2.9 that you could take advantage of.  Not to mention [bugs fixed](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1.3/CHANGES.txt) long ago that you may be running into.

The other, quicker option would be to install 1.2.9 on your Windows machine.  Probably the easiest way to do this, would be to zip-up your Cassandra dir on Ubuntu (minus the data, commitlog, and saved caches dirs of course), copy it to your Windows machine, and expand it.  Then the cqlsh versions would match-up, and you could solve your immediate problem.